# Como centralizar o texto do option do select?

Tags: html5

Galera, como eu posso centralizar o texto do option que fica dentro do select? Ou não existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255132/8063

Comment: Se vc acha que vale a pena carregar um plugin apenas para ter o texto das `options` centralizado, dá uma olhada no link do comentário acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não é possível!**. Fazer isto deve funcionar em **"alguns"** navegadores e em outros não (presumo que somente **Firefox Desktop**):

```css
.main {
    width: 100px;
}

.main option {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<select class="main">
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
    <option>Baz</option>
</select>
```

O motivo de não funcionar na maioria é pelo que eu já explique detalhadamente neste link:

### **- [Como forçar que os elementos  apareçam abaixo do  no IE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3830/3635)**

Diferente da maioria dos elementos, os `<option>`s geralmente não são renderizados pelo *[motor de renderização do navegador](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanismo_de_renderiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o)*, mas sim pela aplicação maior que é separada de tal motor, em outras palavras quem "renderiza" eles é a "aplicação" e está aplicação *"pega"* os *options* dentro do `<select>` no momento que você "clica" e transforma em um Widget ([Widgets de alto nível](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget#Classifica.C3.A7.C3.A3o)) que quando selecionado um dos itens ele envia uma resposta de volta para o motor.

Então o elemento `<option>` é como se fosse apenas uma "base de dados" que o navegador envia para a aplicação e por sua vez a aplicação gera o "Widget de alto nível".

Veja um exemplo são os smartphones que ao invés de mostrar os itens sobrepostos (*dropdown list*) é mostrado algo como:

[image: dropdown-list em diversos sistemas]

Ou seja o próprio browser pode gerar, ou passar a tarefa para o sistema e a partir deste ponto recebe os sinais de controle (quando seleciona um item ou cancela), mas não há quase nenhum controle por DOM, por este motivo não é possível customizar o CSS de elementos `<option>`

Então a unica solução garantida é criar um Select simulado.

### Solução alternativa, simulando um combobox

A melhor maneira para contornar este problema é você criar um *combobox (`<select>`) simulado*, usando `<div>`, `<ul>`, `<li>` e `tabindex=""`

Se quiser algo pronto, tente [DropKick](https://github.com/robdel12/DropKick), neste caso deve se customizar a classe `.dk-option`

Exemplo de uso:

```html
<link href="../css/dropkick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../js/dropkick.min.js"></script>

<style>
.dk-option {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<form id="test">
    <select name="tipo" id="combo1">
        <option value="a">tipo a</option>
        <option value="b">tipo b</option>
    </select>

    <select name="setor" id="combo2">
        <option value="a">setor a</option>
        <option value="b">setor b</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
    (function() {
        var combo1 = new Dropkick("#combo1");
        var combo2 = new Dropkick("#combo2");

        combo1.open(); //Abre o combo1
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

cara eu tive o mesmo problema mas consegui resolver

eu tive de fazer uma folha de css e coloquei os seguintes codigos

css:

```css
.select-center{
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}

html:
```

```html
<select class="select-center">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```